# How to improve a LSTM self-attention model given the absence of overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, rnn

I am doing a binary classification on time series data.

Class 0 is a single class but class 1 is actually a combination of 7 different classes.

My objective to classify class 0 from other classes.

The training set has a shape of (4917,100,136) as (batches, timesteps, features).

In the beginning, the model shows significant overfitting problem.

I managed to minimize the overfitting problem through:

1. Reduced layer units.
2. Increased or decreased number of layers( did not affect the model much)
3. Applied regularization through `l2` and `dropout`.

I have also applied `class_weight` to the model to mitigate the unbalanced issue.

I tried different `Adam` and `RMSprop`, not much difference.

```
    Dense_unit = 32
    LSTM_unit = 32
    
    dense_reg = 0.003
    attention_param = LSTM_unit*2
    attention_init_value = 1.0/attention_param
    
    
    u_train = np.full((X_train.shape[0], attention_param),
                      attention_init_value, dtype=np.float32)
    u_val = np.full((X_val.shape[0],attention_param),
                     attention_init_value, dtype=np.float32)
    u_test = np.full((X_test.shape[0],attention_param),
                     attention_init_value, dtype=np.float32)
    
    
    with keras.backend.name_scope('BLSTMLayer'):
        # Bi-directional Long Short-Term Memory for learning the temporal aggregation
        input_feature = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]))
        x = Masking(mask_value=0)(input_feature)
        
        x = Dense(Dense_unit,kernel_regularizer=l2(dense_reg), activation='relu')(x)
        
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
        x = Dense(Dense_unit,kernel_regularizer=l2(dense_reg),activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
        x = Dense(Dense_unit,kernel_regularizer=l2(dense_reg),activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)



        y = Bidirectional(LSTM(LSTM_unit,activity_regularizer=l2(0.0029),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.002),recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.002),return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout))(x)
        y = Bidirectional(LSTM(LSTM_unit,activity_regularizer=l2(0.0029),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.002),recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.002),return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout))(y)
   

    with keras.backend.name_scope('AttentionLayer'):
        # Logistic regression for learning the attention parameters with a standalone feature as input
        input_attention = Input(shape=(LSTM_unit * 2,))
        u = Dense(LSTM_unit * 2, activation='softmax')(input_attention)

        # To compute the final weights for the frames which sum to unity
        alpha = dot([u, y], axes=-1)  # inner prod.
        alpha = Activation('softmax')(alpha)

    with keras.backend.name_scope('WeightedPooling'):
        # Weighted pooling to get the utterance-level representation
        z = dot([alpha, y], axes=1)

    # Get posterior probability for each emotional class
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(z)

    model = Model(inputs=[input_attention, input_feature], outputs=output)
    
    optimizer = opt_select(optimizer,learning_rate)
    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=optimizer)
    
    print(model.summary())

    
    hist = model.fit([u_train, X_train], 
                     y_train, 
                     shuffle=False,
                     batch_size=batch_size, 
                     epochs=epochs, 
                     class_weight = {0:1.75607143,1:0.69903327},
                     validation_data=([u_val, X_val], y_val)
                    )
```

### The training accuracy is very close to the validation accuracy(orange line) as shown in the screenshot. Further regularization didn't improve validation accuracy.

Questions:

How can one improve the model under these situations?

The self-attention actually did not make the prediction better than models contains only pure LSTM.

Can anyone suggest how to apply more self-attention layers into the model?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accuracy goes straight for about 200 epochs then start increasing](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88532/accuracy-goes-straight-for-about-200-epochs-then-start-increasing)

Comment: @DavidMasip This question is more about how to further improve this model given most techniques have been applied. A step further to decrease the loss.

Comment: I am looking for suggestions like the number of `units` should be set for the layers. Or maybe why having a few `dense` layers before `LSTM` layers yield better outcome (10% better) than having only `LSTM` layers. Thanks